# instancedBuffergeometry with spritesheet doesn't show up from threejs v117

Tags: three.js

I'm using InstancedBufferGeometry to draw many `.gltf` objects and using spritesheet like https://i.stack.imgur.com/5SCng.jpg to apply many kinds of texture.

To use spritesheet, I'm using material based on MeshLambertMaterial using `onBeforeCompile` function, and before threejs v116, it was working perfectly.

But after upgrading threejs and `GLTFLoader` to v117, nothing is displayed.

I'm implementing `onBeforeCompile` like this:

```js
class InstancedLambertMaterial extends THREE.MeshLambertMaterial {
  constructor(params) {
    super(params);
    this.spriteGrids = params?.spriteGrids;
    this.userData = {
      uniforms: {
        vUvScale: { value: 1 / Math.sqrt(params?.spriteGrids) }
      }
    };
  }
  onBeforeCompile(shader) {
    Object.assign(shader.uniforms, this.userData.uniforms);

    shader.vertexShader = `#define USE_INSTANCING_CUSTOM\n${shader.vertexShader}`;

    const instancedAttributes = `
attribute vec3 translation;
attribute vec4 orientation;
attribute vec3 scale;
attribute vec2 vUvOffsets;
varying vec2 v_vUvOffsets;
uniform float vUvScale;
`;
    shader.vertexShader = shader.vertexShader.replace('#include <common>', `${instancedAttributes}\n#include <common>`);

    const replacedProjectVertex = `
vec4 mvPosition = vec4( transformed, 1.0 );
#ifdef USE_INSTANCING
  mvPosition = instanceMatrix * mvPosition;
#endif
#ifdef USE_INSTANCING_CUSTOM
  vUv = uv;
  transformed *= scale;
  vec3 vcV = cross(orientation.xyz, transformed);
  transformed = vcV * (2.0 * orientation.w) + (cross(orientation.xyz, vcV) * 2.0 + transformed);
  mvPosition = vec4(translation + transformed, 1.0);
#endif
mvPosition = modelViewMatrix * mvPosition;
gl_Position = projectionMatrix * mvPosition;

#ifdef USE_INSTANCING_CUSTOM
    v_vUvOffsets = vUvOffsets;
#endif
    `;
    shader.vertexShader = shader.vertexShader.replace('#include <project_vertex>', replacedProjectVertex);

    shader.fragmentShader = `#define USE_SPRITESHEET\n${shader.fragmentShader}`;

    const spriteSheetUniforms = `
#include <map_pars_fragment>
#ifdef USE_SPRITESHEET
  uniform float vUvScale;
  varying vec2 v_vUvOffsets;
#endif
    `;
    shader.fragmentShader = shader.fragmentShader.replace('#include <map_pars_fragment>', spriteSheetUniforms);

    const spriteSheetTexelColorBranch = `
#ifdef USE_SPRITESHEET
  vec4 texelColor = texture2D( map, (vUv * vUvScale) + (v_vUvOffsets * vUvScale) );
  texelColor = mapTexelToLinear( texelColor );
  diffuseColor *= texelColor;
#endif
    `;
    shader.fragmentShader = shader.fragmentShader.replace('#include <map_fragment>', spriteSheetTexelColorBranch);

    this.userData = shader;
  }
}
```

and preparing each transformation attributes like this and apply it.

```js
const scales       = new THREE.InstancedBufferAttribute(new Float32Array(instances * 3), 3, false);
const translations = new THREE.InstancedBufferAttribute(new Float32Array(instances * 3), 3, false);
const orientations = new THREE.InstancedBufferAttribute(new Float32Array(instances * 4), 4, false);
const tex_vec      = new THREE.InstancedBufferAttribute(new Float32Array(instances * 2), 2, false);
```

I checked shader output(by raising shader error deliberately) and looks like nothing is changed related to draw my objects.
I looked into [relase notes of v117](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/releases/tag/r117), but looks like nothing changed related to my projects.
I want to be able to execute these codes for the newest version of threejs.

I made an working example. Both code is same, except version of threejs and `GLTFLoader`.
this is the result of v116
https://jsfiddle.net/maemaemae3/o9t1wxrm/1/
and v117
https://jsfiddle.net/maemaemae3/2cgym7n3/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this line:

> const igeo = new THREE.InstancedBufferGeometry().copy(geometry);

If you do this, properties of `InstancedBufferGeometry` become `undefined` since they do not exist in `BufferGeometry`. A refactoring in `r117` made this error visible.

I've fixed your second fiddle by restoring the `instanceCount` property:https://jsfiddle.net/9k4oqerc/

Comment: Thank you very much, it was fixed!
I had to define `igeo.instanceCount = void 0;` in old versions because if I set small number to instanceCount, the number can't be increased.
But It looks like not needed now.
Is this behaviour fixed?

Comment: The problem is your copy operation which makes the property `instanceCount` `undefined`. You should copy over buffer attributes manually instead.